# Draw smooth rectangle around an image (with animation)

Tags: vb.net

I have created a project in VB in which I am showing a image on PictrueBox with full screen also I set padding 10 around the image with the backcolor "black".
Now I am trying to draw a rectangle on the padding area with "red" color that will fill like a line is drawing from 0,0 position to screen width position.
I am using Graphics of Paint event to draw a Rectangle and increasing the width of the Rectangle in BG worker.
Everything is working fine and feels like a red border is drawing with animation, but animation is not like smooth and it is looking like jumpy (during the animation).

I want a smooth animation in VB not like jumpy, Can I do smooth animation kind of in VB?

```
'code of myScreen_paint event
Private Sub myScreen_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PicturePlayer.Paint
    ' Create solid brush.
    Dim blueBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)

    ' Create rectangle
    rect = New Rectangle(0, 0, posX, 10)
End Sub

'code of Background Worker that redraw Rectangle (but not animation like smooth but jumpy)
Private Sub BgWorkerProg_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgWorkerProg.DoWork
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    While True
        If BgWorkerProg.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Return
        End If
        posX = posX + ((Me.Width / (PlayingAsset.Duration / 2)) / 4) ' duration is the time to show the image on screen.
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Refresh()

    End While

End Sub
```

Please if someone could help me here.
Thanks

Comment: 1) Better to use a `Timer` instead of a `BackgroundWorker` to set the new values and `Invalidate()` the paint. 2) You should call the `Invalidate` method of the drawing canvas (The PictureBox in your case) and not of the `Me`. 3) Don't call the `Refresh` method. 4) You should dispose the graphics objects at the end of the `Paint` event. 5) Maybe you need to increase the `posX` with small amounts each time to avoid that jumpy effect.

Comment: "duration is the time to show the image on screen"  If you have specific time that the animation should take, then use DateTime and TimeSpan to determine the width of the box based on the current time.  Then use a Timer as suggested by dr.null.  You can change the Interval to control how often then animation updates, and it will still always be the correct width based on the time calculations.